# Android Speech Recognision change return language

Tags: java, android, localization, speech-to-text

I'm working on an android app which takes voice input and sets the result text into a `TextView`. Though the language of the speech to be recognized is not English, the result text the app is providing is English. To put it in an elaborate way, the speech recognition intent I am creating is like this:

```java
Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("bn").setScript("Beng").setRegion("BD").build();
intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,locale);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES,locale);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,locale);
```

And the RecognitionListener `onResult()` method looks like this:

```java
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ArrayList<String> voiceResults = results
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    if (voiceResults == null) {
        text = "";
        Log.e("Listener","No voice results");
    } else {
        text = voiceResults.get(0);
        display.setText(text);
    }
}
```

I want the `results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)` to return an ArrayList consisting of Bengali letters.

The Expected behavior:

[image: want image like this]

Current output:

[image: wrong display image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE

\n this extra is boolean, you are sending Locale object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following method to achieve the desired output, set `bn-BD`:

```
 private void getAudioInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "bn-BD");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "I am Listening...");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {

        }
    }
```

Then use `onActivityResult()` to receive the result using the same Request Code that you've used in the `startActivityForResult()` with the intent like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                if (result != null) {
                    bangla_text = result.get(0);
                    textOutput.setText(bangla_text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```